# Error displayed at end of of "apt-get upgrade" command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, gnome, kde

i have following error while upgrade packages on terminal..
that have no any problem to updating packages but end of it display following error

> Errors were encountered while processing:
>
> `desktop-base`
>
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

username@hostname:~$

Comment: Did you try "sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing" ?

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but it didn't.  it displaying every time at installation.  following error are displayd                                                                   `Setting up desktop-base (9.0.5+kali1) ...
update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/desktop-grub': Invalid argument
dpkg: error processing package desktop-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 desktop-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit longer so I try to post here.

Maybe **"apt-get -f install"** to force an install of the files that didn't get loaded because of the error. Then try **"apt-get upgrade"** again, **"apt-get -f install"** back and forth until only the package that has the error is left.

Or try **"cd /etc/alternatives/"** and  **"ls -l desktop-grub"**

Should give you something like **lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 54 Mär 10 17:59 desktop-grub -> /usr/share/desktop-base/active-theme/grub/grub-4x3.png** .

Maybe some links are broken and you could try to fix it with **yes '' | update-alternatives --force --all**

Comment: the out put of `ls -l desktop-grub` is     `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 107759 Aug  1 11:51 desktop-grub`

Comment: and the out put of yes '`yes '' | update-alternatives --force --all` is [link]( http://www.writeurl.com/text/mtatggcrikbpci82seqj/494q87klydb6sgsdfg8e ) not any changes for  desktp-base

Comment: It displayed before  following error `update-alternatives: error: cannot stat file '/etc/alternatives/desktop-grub': Invalid argument`